# Does VCRedist contain MFC dependencies?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

In other words, does installing the VC redistributable with my application is all I need to take care of dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It contains the MFC-specific dependencies, yes.  Also the C runtime.